# Strange delegate dealloc call after applicationWillEnterForeground from Facebook SSO

Tags: facebook, background, single-sign-on, dealloc, foreground

I have searched quite a while for this answer with the following keywords on Google but I got nothing:

+applicationDidEnterBackground +applicationWillEnterForeground +Facebook +dealloc +SSO

Here is my problem statement:

If I press home button to suspend the application and click on the app icon to resume it, no matter how many times I tried, the following function will be called in the correct order, with no dealloc function being called:

```
applicationDidEnterBackground - upon pressing home button
applicationWillEnterForeground - upon pressing app icon
```

Then, if within an App I start a call to Facebook's SSO:

```
[facebook authorize:_permissions delegate:self];
```

Strange things happen:

```
applicationDidEnterBackground - upon Facebook SSO
```

Press home button to exit Safari's Facebook SSO page

```
applicationWillEnterForeground - upon pressing app icon
```

delegate's dealloc is called soon after applicationWillEnterForeground ends

(very first function called after some assembly codes:

```
mov    0x56314c(%ebx),%esi
xor    %eax,%eax
test   %al,%al
mov    0x8(%ebp),%ecx
```

=> dealloc

I don't really know what is going on here, and I have tried to search for the answers on Google for quite a while now, can someone help to explain why this is happening?

I am using Facebook version "kSDKVersion = @"2";".

*Additional Information:*

After taking a look into the problem, I think the problem lies deeper within how my view controller interacts with navigation controller when the app enters foreground again:

My Facebook SSO is invoked within RegistrationViewController's XIB where user clicks a button to enter SSO session, to display the RegistrationViewController, I used the following codes:

```
[_delegate.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
_delegate.regViewController = [[RegistrationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[_delegate.navigationController pushViewController:_delegate.regViewController animated:NO];
[_delegate.regViewController release];
```

After user clicks the button inside RegistrationViewController, Safari is opened.
Pressing home button to exit Safari and clicking the app icon will first call:

```
applicationWillEnterForeground
```

Then it calls the dealloc function of RegistrationViewController, which is the part I don't understand, since RegistrationViewController should have been retained by Navigation Controller isn't it? Why is it executing the dealloc?

Also, within my RegistrationViewController dealloc routine, since I have declared a _delegate pointer within my RegistrationViewController using sharedApplication, I think it is only logical to dealloc it when RegistrationViewController no longer is needed, but why  would [_delegate release] lead to a permanent demise of my delegate? Shouldn't delegate be retained by someone else all the time?

Comment: I found a very interesting URL with some information on multi-threads:

http://cocoa-dom.tumblr.com/post/866039292/the-hidden-complexity-of-ios-4-multitasking

it says:

"if opening an URL/push notification means you jump to another location in your app, the code handing that opening needs to be able to dismiss any - and i mean any - currently showing UI and present itself. This can be a very tough one."

I am not sure if my problem is related to this though...

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem is that the fact I am releasing what I shouldn't be releasing!

The following statement:

```
_delegate = (PHPConnectDemoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

will not increment the retain count to the app delegate by 1.

Therefore it is not necessary within the same View Controller's dealloc function to perform:

```
[_delegate release];
```

or else the retain count to your app delegate drops down to 0 hence leading to a permanent demise of your app delegate.

Somehow I think the assembly code I pasted is performing assessment on the retain count to decide whether to dealloc the app delegate or not, correct me if I am wrong.